# Open External WooCommerce Products in New Tabs - Adding Attribute target="_blank"

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I have managed to add attribute `target="_blank"` to my external product pages but I can't seem to change the links on the parent (grouped product) pages.

I was able to do this by modifying external.php and just adding the tag to the actual link itself.

```
<p class="cart">
<?php sdnetwork(); sdcondition(); parent_permalink_button(); ?><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $product_url ); ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><img src="/wp-content/themes/wootique-child/images/icons/new_tab_icon.gif" alt="Opens in New Tab"> <?php echo esc_html( $button_text ); ?></a>
</p>
```

How can I change the links on the parent page of grouped products to add this attribute, my first thought was to modify grouped.php but the link is generated differently.

```
<?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart(); ?>
```

How can I possibly add my tag to the link that is generated above? I've thought about using a hook but I need some help.

EDIT:

Just wondering if I could use jQuery like so.....

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".button.product_type_external").each(function() {
    $(this).find("a").attr("target", "_blank");
  });
});
```

The problem is most of the links are hidden when the page is loaded and I'm worried this may take up alot of resources or will it? Quite new to jQuery.

http://mobilereactor.co.uk/shop/mobile-phones/sony-xperia-z5-compact-coral-deals/

EDIT Solved thanks to cale_b:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'add_target_blank', 10, 2 );

function add_target_blank( $link, $product ){
    global $post;
    $product = get_product( $post->ID );
        if( $product->is_type( 'external' ) ){
            // I simply added target="_blank" in the line below
            $link = sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" target="_blank" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>',
                    esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
                    esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
                    esc_attr( $product->id ),
                    esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
                    esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
                    esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
                );
            return $link;
        } else {
            // I simply remove target="_blank" in the line below
            $link = sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>',
                    esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
                    esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
                    esc_attr( $product->id ),
                    esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
                    esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
                    esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
                );
            return $link;
        }
}
```

Comment: Don't use jQuery.  There's a template that will allow you to override the links, just like your `external.php`.   You've drastically modified the template that you've linked to, so you're going to need to give us a bit more to work with.  Which template are we looking at in your link above?

Comment: in the link above its a modded version of grouped.php

Comment: I think the link is generated by ```<?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart(); ?>``` in grouped.php though don't know how to mod it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trace the code, that function does some things, and then loads the template `loop/add-to-cart.php`.

If you open `loop/add-to-cart.php`, you'll find code that should look something like this:

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
    sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        esc_attr( $product->id ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
$product );
```

To modify the link, use the filter (`woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link`).

Note: never modify the WooCommerce templates directly in the plugin folder.  Use their excellent [Template Structure](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) to copy the template to your theme and modify it there, otherwise your changes will get lost the next time you update WooCommerce.

Final note: tracing the code is *easy* and fun to do when you use a good IDE.  I for one am a huge fan of PHPStorm (https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/).

**EDIT**

To *only* add it for external products, then you would take a different approach.

You would leverage the filter, and as you mention in the comments, write a function in your functions.php that does something like this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'my_external_product_links', 10, 2);

function my_external_product_links( $link, $product ) {
    // Set up the $target variable to contain the correct text depending on the product
    $target = ( 'external' == $product->product_type  ) ? 'target="_blank"' : '';
    // Use the code from the core function here, but with our modification to include target
    echo sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s" %s>%s</a>',
            esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
            esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
            esc_attr( $product->id ),
            esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
            esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
            esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ),
            $target
        );
}
```

In the code above, pay close attention to the new `%s` in the `sprintf` statement:

```
// Watch for this --->--->--->--->--->--->--->--->--->--->--->--->--->--->--->--->--->--->-->--->--->-vv
'<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s" %s>
```

Comment: This is very helpful thank you if I create a function in ```functions.php``` to only ```echo target="_blank"``` in the case of an external product would that be the correct way of doing this? as I assume this manages single products also ??

Comment: I was thinking it could be much simpler using your information ```function target_blank() {
 global $post;
 $product = get_product( $post->ID );
  if( $product->is_type( 'external' ) ){
   echo 'target="_blank"';
  }
}
``` then just pop ```target_blank();``` into the add-to-cart.php template - will it work though??

Comment: just tried it didn't work lol thanks for the help much appreciated

Comment: so should the add filter be ```add_filter('add_to_cart', 'my_external_product_links');``` I don't quite understand this part and how does the _blank get added?

Comment: I tried just adding _blank to the add-to-cart.php but that caused all woocom buttons to open in new tab guess its the high road

Comment: the function doesn't work though cale where is the _blank added?

Comment: I'm sorry, I had a couple more typos.  I've completely updated the function - please try it again - should work for you this time!

Comment: this crashes the site - I think there must be an error, I can see in my editor some brackets arnt closed of properly

Comment: Yep, missing a closing quote.  Should be `$target = ( 'external' == $product->product_type  ) ? 'target="_blank"' : '';` - fixed in answer.

Comment: that also breaks the function of the site I have now solved this problem and modified your function please check the question I will post the answer

Answer (score 3):

Here is a cleaner way to add `target="_blank"` to add_to_cart links to open them in new tab:

```
function ns_open_in_new_tab($args, $product) 
{
    if( $product->is_type('external') ) {
        // Inject target="_blank" into the attributes array
        $args['attributes']['target'] = '_blank';
    }    

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args', 'ns_open_in_new_tab', 10, 2 );
```

Replace `ns_` part with your own namespace abbreviation.